# What is the programmer's default selection for implementation of priority queue?

Tags: c++, data-structures, heap, priority-queue

Is it:

- Heap?
- Unsorted List?
- Sorted List?
- Linked list?
- Any other data structure?

Which one of them is the default/natural choice of programmers when implementing priority queue and what is the reason of preference of that particular choice over the other?

Comment: The Wikipedia article answers most of these questions: http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Priority_queue

Comment: This is an interesting question, but it's too subjective to be answered here.  Typically you'd just use whatever is available in your Language of Choice unless there was a reason to use something more advanced, like a Fibonacci heap or van Emde Boas Queue.

Comment: std::priority queue typically uses a heap.

Answer (score 2):

I would recommend implementing a Ladder Queue, which is an `O(1)` priority queue.

Formal definition: [Ladder queue: An O(1) priority queue structure for large-scale discrete event simulation](http://dl.acm.org/citation.cfm?id=1103324)

Comment: They are selling the article for $15.

Comment: qiao: =]. About article price: you can get it for free through library or university networks.

Comment: Does any of that money go to the authors?

Answer (score 0):

I would say heap for speed.

list has linear access times while a heap O(log(n)) access is possible (insert/delete) while lists allow for deletemin in O(1) but have O(n) for insertions

Comment: I'll add that heaps can be instantiated in O(n), while a sorted list needs to be instantiated in O(nlogn)

Answer (score 0):

On the odd occasions I've needed a priority queue, there has been only a small set of priorities, so I've been able to get away with an array of 'ordinary' FIFO queues, indexed by priority.  The pop() method iterates the array from the highest-priority end looking for a non-zero count.